# SQL Select Group By Max Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Can someone give me a select statement that would retrieve only the rows with the highest (max) YEAR for each user?

```
Year    User_ID   Name     City
=====   =======   =====    =====
2001    1         Bob      Mpls
2002    1         Bob      Mpls
2003    1         Bob      St Paul
2005    2         Mary     New York
2010    2         Mary     L.A.
```

...so the result set I would want is:

```
Year    User_ID   Name   City
=====   =======   ====   =====
2003    1         Bob    St Paul
2010    2         Mary   L.A.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not mention any RDBMS, this query will work on almost all RDBMS.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Name, MAX(Year) Year
            FROM    TableName 
            GROUP   BY Name
        ) b ON  a.Name = b.Name
                AND a.Year = b.Year
```

However, if your RDBMS supports window functions, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT  Year, User_ID, Name
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  Year, User_ID, Name,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name,
                                        ORDER BY Year DESC) rn
            FROM    TableName
        ) x
WHERE   x.rn = 1
```

Comment: I do believe you can do the window function in the main query and not a sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table a
  WHERE a.Year = (
                    SELECT TOP 1 Year 
                       FROM Table b 
                       WHERE a.name = b.name 
                       ORDER BY year DESC
                  )
```

not the best i know but simple

Comment: The subquery will return exactly 1 year. So this isn't even right.

Comment: 1 year the top one per name. is that not what he is wanting? i tested it on a sample table i happen to have up and it worked for me

Comment: TOP is not supported in all databases. Do you know what database the OP is using?

Comment: Very true Racil, I guess i don't

Comment: I'm using sql server. Also, i added another field in the example, which seems to add an additional row I don't want in the result set - both cities for each user)

Comment: if you don't want it don't select it just select the names of the columns you do want.

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked too. I set the accepted answer to john woo since he responded first. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT MAX( Year ) Year, User_id, Name
FROM tableName
GROUP BY User_id, Name
```

Comment: have to group by name also but yeah grouping always works well

Answer (score 0):

If you tell us the database you're using, I may recommend a slightly better query, but this one is simple and should work in most databases:

```
SELECT MAX(year), user_id, name
FROM myTable
GROUP BY user_id, name
```

Comment: No output for the City would be generated with this SELECT statement.

Comment: @JohnH If you comment on old threads, at least read the thread carefully first. I posted my answer before the OP edited the question and added the city. The same applies to most other answers to this question.

Comment: Sorry, I would not have added the comment nor the down arrow had I know that. I can undo the down arrow, but only if your answer is edited. Perhaps a comment about how the "City" column was added after the original answer was posted? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnH Why are you doing this? Did somebody hire you to investigate old threads on SO? Do you even understand how SO works? The OP asked a question, we answered it and the answers were correct. The OP cannot go and change the question after that because it makes the answers wrong which is not fair to the people who spent their time helping for free. The OP should've posted a new question. I don't see a need for the note, it's clear to anybody who can read. Thank you for the downvote of ignorance. Next time read carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive the result by group by ,see sample example below ..

```
    create table #temp(year int,id int,name varchar(5),city varchar(20))
insert into #temp values (2001,1,'Bob','Mpls')
insert into  #temp values (2002,1,'Bob','Mpls')
insert into  #temp values  (2003,1,'Bob','St Paul')
insert into  #temp values  (2005,2,'Mary','New York')
insert into  #temp values  (2010,2,'Mary','L.A.')
```

you can select like using this query

```
 SELECT  t.year,t.id,t.Name,t.city
FROM    #temp t
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Name, MAX(Year) Year
            FROM    #temp 
            GROUP   BY Name
        ) a ON  t.Name = a.Name
                AND t.Year = a.Year
```